# Конвертация string to double C#

Tags: c#, строки, double

Есть XML файл, из которого я записываю данные в БД приложения. В классе  этой xml входное значение string. Пример тега, в котором записывается значение  `<creditTotalAmt>29,770</creditTotalAmt>`, иногда содержит  `<creditTotalAmt>N</creditTotalAmt>`  . Поэтому сделал конвертацию из string в Double

```
//code
addCred.amtOutstanding = Convert.ToDouble(i.amtOutstanding);
//
```

Некоторые документы, которые приходят выдают ошибку:

> Входная строка имела неверный формат. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Адресат вызова создал исключение. ---> System.FormatException: Входная строка имела неверный формат.
>      в System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
>      в System.Double.Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider)

Что может быть не так?

Comment: В исключении выведите символы на экран или в файл - тогда будет понятно что не так. Что угодно - могут быть пробелы лишнии, точки, возвраты каретки табуляции, пустая строка,  что угодно. Так же можно использовать TryParse

Comment: А почему бы не использовать double.TryParse?

Comment: @nick_n_a не подскажете как вывести это в консоль? Я так понимаю try catch мне в помощь, а вот что именно туда вывести надо?

Comment: `Что может быть не так?` может случиться невалидное значение в поле или другой разделитель разрядов или другая культура на машине, на которой запущен код.

Comment: Ну например i.amtOutstanding  `Console.WriteLine(i.amtOutstanding);` во внутрь `catch` и может ещё какой-то текст. Если записей много - в консоли будет много чего.

Comment: Например, там может быть запятая в качестве разделителя целой и дробной части, а локализация хочет точку, или наоборот там точка, а нужна запятая. Могут быть и пробелы, а могут быть хитрые коды UTF-8, которых даже и на экране не видно при печати.